# Assign variable to entire iterable while simultaneously performing Iterable unpacking in for loop

Tags: python

Is there a way, using [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), in a loop to assign multiple values within an iterable as well as a variable holding all of the iterable.

This is possible not in a loop using:

```
abc = a, b, c = range(3)
```

But in a loop I don't know of a syntactically equivalent option. Currently I would use:

```
it = zip(*[iter(range(9))]*3) #for example

for abc in it:
    a, b, c = abc
    ...
```

Or this:

```
for a, b, c in it:
    abc = [a, b, c]
    ...
```

I want to know if there is a way to have the best of both  worlds here. Something along the lines of the following *(which is not valid although an example of what I mean)*:

```
for (a, b, c := abc) in it:
    ...
```

Comment: I think your existing approaches are fine and I don't understand what concrete *problem you are trying to solve* this way. I don't think "saving a line of code" is a concrete problem within the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, my approaches are valid and they may as well be the best/only approach although it just seems to me that this should be possible or maybe implementation of it considered. I could very well be wrong.

Comment: Take a look at `for_stmt` in the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).  Doesn't seem possible, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can get, due to the constraints on where an assignment expression is allowed, is

```
for a, b, c in (abc := x for x in it):
    ...
```

`x` is bound to the "scope" of the generator expressions, but `abc` is bound in the scope containing the generator expression, i.e., the same scope in which `a`, `b`, and `c` are bound.

If I saw anyone doing this in a code review, though, I'd tell them to just write

```
for abc in it:
    a, b, c = abc
    ...
```

if they really need all four names defined.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does answer my question there would likely be added overhead, and to me it is just unnecessary extra code.

```
from itertools import tee

for abc, (a, b, c) in zip(*tee(it)):
    …
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this:

```
for *abc,a,b,c in (x*2 for x in it):
    print(abc,a,b,c)

(0, 1, 2) 0 1 2
(3, 4, 5) 3 4 5
(6, 7, 8) 6 7 8
```

Or have abc predefined outside the scope of the comprehension:

```
abc = []
for a,b,c in (abc:=x for x in it):
    print(abc,a,b,c)

(0, 1, 2) 0 1 2
(3, 4, 5) 3 4 5
(6, 7, 8) 6 7 8
```